# Linux sockets with C: recv() not returning a delayed chunk

Tags: c, sockets, recv

A friend of mine asked for help with a programming exercise. He's trying to create a simple HTTP client for chunked encoding. Last chunk delayed by 1000 msec doesn't get blocked by select (select doesn't timeout either). I tried removing select and busy-looping recv(), but it seems as the last chunk never arrives (even though it does).

The code is far from clean, filled with what I'd call rather creative choices. But it seems to work for all the other chunks. I just can't wrap my head around what might cause a delayed chunk to break this thing.

Any ideas?

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// check that parameters exist
if (argc != 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of parameters\n");
    return 1;
}

// create addrinfo structure
struct addrinfo info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof info); // set values to 0
info.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // unspecified IP version
info.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP

struct addrinfo *results; // results structure list

// get info using command line parameters
int value = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &info, &results);
// check return value
if (value != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to call getaddrinfo\n");
    return 1;
}

// create socket
int sock = socket(results->ai_family, results->ai_socktype,
                  results->ai_protocol);               
// check return value
if (sock == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create socket\n");
    return 1;
} else {
    // connect to remote host
    int con = connect(sock, results->ai_addr, results->ai_addrlen);
    // check return value
    if (con == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to host\n");
        freeaddrinfo(results);
        return 1;
    }
}

// free memory
freeaddrinfo(results);


// create request
char request[1000];

strcpy(request, "GET ");
strcat(request, argv[3]);
strcat(request, " HTTP/1.1\r\n");

strcat(request, "Host: ");
strcat(request, argv[1]);
strcat(request, "\r\n");

strcat(request, "Accept-Encoding: chunked\r\n\n\n");


// send request
int sent_bytes = send(sock, request, strlen(request) + 1, 0);

// check return value
if (sent_bytes == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to send to remote host\n");
    return 1;
}

printf("\n\nSending...\n\n%s", request);



// receive status
char status[13];
int bytes = recv(sock, status, sizeof status, 0);
printf("\nReceiving...\n\n");

// check return value
if (bytes == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to receive\n");
    return 1;
}
else if (bytes == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Host closed the connection\n");
    return 1;
}

status[12] = '\0';
if (strstr(status, "HTTP/1.1 404")) {
      fprintf(stderr, "404 Not found.\n\n");
      return 1;
  } else if (!(strstr(status, "HTTP/1.1 200"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown response.\n\n");
    return 1;
  }

// status should now be 200 OK



char next[2];
next[1] = '\0';

// check encoding
char* encoding = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
while (1) {
    char *temp = (char*)realloc(encoding, strlen(encoding) + 2);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to realloc\n");
        free(encoding);
        return 1;
    }
    encoding = temp;
    bytes = recv(sock, next, 1, 0);
    if (bytes == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to receive\n");
        free(encoding);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (bytes == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Host closed the connection\n");
        free(encoding);
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy(encoding + strlen(encoding), next, 2);
    if (strstr(encoding, "transfer-encoding: chunked")) {
        free(encoding);
          break;
      }
      if (strstr(encoding, "\r\n\r\n")) {
        free(encoding);
          fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported encoding\n");
          return 1;
      }
}

// encoding should now be chunked


// read until message chunks begin
char* rest = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
while (1) {
    char *temp = (char*)realloc(rest, strlen(rest) + 2);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to realloc\n");
        free(rest);
        return 1;
    }
    rest = temp;
    bytes = recv(sock, next, 1, 0);
    if (bytes == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to receive\n");
        free(rest);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (bytes == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Host closed the connection\n");
        free(rest);
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy(rest + strlen(rest), next, 2);
      if (strstr(rest, "\r\n\r\n")) {
        free(rest);
          break;
      }
}


// read chunks
char* response = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(char));

while (1) {

    char chunksize_string[10];
    chunksize_string[0] = '\0';

    fd_set readfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sock, &readfds);
    tv.tv_sec = 10;
    tv.tv_usec = 500000;

    // read chunksize
    while (1) {
        int rv = select(sock + 1, &readfds, 0, 0, &tv);
        if (rv == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in select\n");
            return 1;
        } else if (rv == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Timeout occured\n");
            return 1;
        }

        bytes = recv(sock, next, 1, MSG_WAITALL);
        if (bytes == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to receive\n");
            free(response);
            return 1;
        }
        else if (bytes == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Host closed the connection\n");
            free(response);
            return 1;
        }
        memcpy(chunksize_string + strlen(chunksize_string), next, 2);
        if (strstr(next, "\n")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    unsigned int chunksize;
    sscanf(chunksize_string, "%x\r\n", &chunksize);

    if (chunksize == 0) {
        break;
    }

    // read chunk
    char chunk[chunksize + 1];
    bytes = recv(sock, chunk, chunksize, 0);
    if (bytes == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to receive\n");
        free(response);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (bytes == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Host closed the connection\n");
        free(response);
        return 1;
    }
    chunk[chunksize] = '\0';

    // reallocate space in response
    char *temp = (char*)realloc(response, strlen(response) + chunksize + 1);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to realloc\n");
        free(response);
        return 1;
    }
    response = temp;

    // add chunk to response
    memcpy(response + strlen(response), chunk, chunksize + 1);

    // read "\r\n"
    char t[2];
    bytes = recv(sock, t, 2, 0);
    if (bytes == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to receive\n");
        free(rest);
        return 1;
    }

}

printf("%s", response);

free(response);

// close the connection
close(sock);

return 0;
}
```

The node.js server is as follows:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();

server.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    response.status(200);
    response.header('transfer-encoding', 'chunked');

    response.write('First line\n');
    response.write('Second line\n');
    response.write('Third line first part --');
    response.write('and a second part\n');

    setTimeout(function() {
        response.end('Delayed line\n');
    }, 1000);   

    return next();
});

server.listen(9999);
```

Comment: What's the OS ? Indent your code please.

Comment: Have you used Wireshark to make sure that the node.js server sends all chunks before closing the connection (i.e. before sending a FIN packet)?

Answer (score 1):

That code is indeed a bit dodgy. Cant suggest any surefire fix, but these will help:

1) Initialize all variables and reserved space before use. E.g., `char request[1000] = {0};`, `unsigned int chunksize = 0;` etc

2) Fix the use of `select()`. You have select inside while() where you are reading 1 byte at a time, so it will probably loop multiple times. Take into account, that select modifies the fdset and the timeout parameter. Those need to be set correctly for every iteration of the loop.

3) Fix the use of `recv()`. In reading the chunk, the code assumes recv returns "chunksize" amount of data. At least check that it does. Same applies when receiving the status.

p.s. Compile with all warnings enabled and read the compiler output. Fix all suggested errors.

Comment: 4) Whenever `errno` is set by a function call, use `perror("blah")` instead of `fprintf(stderr, "blah\n")` to print the actual error.